# Problem with dependencies while installing ubuntu-sdk on 16.04

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-sdk

I get this error while installing ubuntu-sdk on clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 64bit:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: autopilot-desktop but it is not installable
              Depends: intltool but it is not installable
              Depends: libcontent-hub-doc but it is not installable
              Depends: phablet-tools but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ubuntu-device-flash but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ubuntu-sdk-ide but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Please use code formatting when posting logs/errors.

Comment: To solve your problem try this `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install some dependencies separately one by one.
In my case it was throwing :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: phablet-tools but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ubuntu-sdk-ide but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So i first tried to install phablet-tools :

```
sudo apt install phablet-tools
```

It throws :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phablet-tools : Depends: android-tools-adb (>= 4.2.2)
                 Depends: android-tools-fastboot (>= 4.2.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So i have then install android-tools-adb and android-tools-fastboot one by one using :

```
sudo apt install android-tools-adb
sudo apt install android-tools-fastboot
```

Then i again tried to install ubuntu-sdk using :

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk
```

And it worked .

So the whole point is that , You have to install all dependencies one by one .
It applies for any package you want to install, not only for ubuntu-sdk.

Comment: This was also what fixed my problem, on 14.04. I had to go through the dependencies, and I found that `ubuntu-device-flash` wasn't able to be installed because it had dependencies on packages that weren't available in 14.04. In Synaptic, I forced installing an older version of `ubuntu-device-flash` and then I was finally able to install `ubuntu-sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting errors like unmet dependencies when installing sdk you need to install all the dependencies that mention in error.
then finally install ubuntu-sdk. It works fine.